# Can I add individual kWh measurements to get the total?

Tags: electricity, statistics

I have a time series file showing kWh electricity use measurements from a building every 15 minutes. For example:

```
12:00  100 kWh
12:15  302 kWh
12:30  85 kWh
12:45  97 kWh
```

If I want to work out the building's total electricity use (in kWh) over a 24 h period, would it be appropriate to simply add up all of the individual measurements for that day?

Comment: Yes, power is a scalar quantity and has only magnitude so you can add up the individual ones for the total. In this case if you simply add, then you will get total power for the time period 12:00-12:45

Comment: @Korra Power is measured in watts, the kilowatt-hour is a unit of energy.

Comment: Are you sure the individual numbers are energy (kWh) and not power (kW)? It's easy to measure the current power consumption and usual to derive the energy by multiplying that with the duration. In any case you can just add up energy.

Comment: @planetmaker Yes, I am sure the individual numbers are energy (kWh). Thank you for your comment and answer.

Comment: @PM 2Ring yes, sorry. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. These are measurements of energy because energy equals power (measured in kilowatts) multiplied by time (measured in hours). The total energy wasted is simply the sum of the wasted energies for every 15 minutes because energy is a scalar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: no problemo :))